# Neural Nets using Keras invalid dimensions error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am working on Tensorflow 1.5 for Mnist dataset. When I am fitting my model its says

> expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

see my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
(train_imgs, train_labels ) , (test_imgs , test_labels ) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape = (784,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation=tf.nn.relu) )
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_imgs,train_labels,epochs=5)
```

Is it due to version dependency or code error?

or do I have to reshape the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
(train_imgs, train_labels ) , (test_imgs , test_labels ) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

You have to reshape. MLPs like your model is - don't take 2 dimensional arrays.
Reshape by:

```
train_x = train_imgs.reshape(60000, 28*28)
test_x = test_imgs.reshape(10000, 28*28)

# you need to 1-hot encode your labels
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

def one_hot_encode(labels, universe=None):
    """
    This one hot encoder works with categorical and numeric data, both.
    `universe=` you use, if labels don't contain all categories/numbers.
    Or if you want the 1hot encoding to be in a special order (not the
    automatic alphabetic order).
    `labels=` are the categories/numbers as labels to be 1hot encoded.
    """
    if universe is None:
        universe = sorted(list(set(labels)))
    nums = LabelEncoder().fit(universe).transform(labels)
    one_hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit(np.array(universe).reshape(-1, 1))\
              .transform(np.array(nums).reshape(-1, 1))
    return one_hot

train_labels_1h = one_hot_encode(train_labels)
test_labels_1h  = one_hot_encode(test_labels)

# define epochs
epochs = 5

# define model
def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape = (784,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation=tf.nn.relu) )
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam')
    return model

# "instanciate" a model
model = create_model()

# then run
model.fit(train_x, train_labels_1h, epochs=epochs)
```

And then use them for training and test.

Comment: I passed this `train_x` in `model.fit()` then it shows following ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (60000, 1)

Comment: @AashishPawar Now it will work - see my updated answer. It seems you have to learn about one hot encoding etc. For multiclass classification, when you use "categorical_crossentropy", you have to one hot encode the labels.

Comment: see e.g. https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/

Comment: Which package ? List sort ?

Comment: sure but in google colab you can install your packages, too.

Comment: just do from jupyternotebook: `!pip install scikit-learn` to install it. The `!` from inside a jupyter notebook cell means that this command is for the shell (bash).

Comment: I know how to install package in colab but I think its already installed

Comment: @AashishPawar you do it exactly like I said `!pip install scikit-learn` - but sklearn is aldready installed. But you wrote `sort` not installed. Use `sorted`. Corrected.